# Check item selected on two spinners?

Tags: java, android, select, spinner

I have two spinners on my layout as below:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String STATE_SCALE = "state-scale";
    private static final String STATE_CENTER_X = "state-center-x";
    private static final String STATE_CENTER_Y = "state-center-y";
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        String text3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (text1.equals("Harris Academy"))
            Harris(spinner1);
        if (text1.equals("Harris Academy") && text3.equals("Ground Floor")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView =
                        (SubsamplingScaleImageView) findViewById(id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageAsset("DSC00277.png");

                if (savedInstanceState != null && 
                        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
                        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
                        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {
                    imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE),
                            new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X),
                            savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Could not load asset", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when the app starts it gets the value of spinner 1 and spinner 3 and then does something depending on the values.

How do I extend it so that when I select an item on either spinner it does something based on the new values?

Comment: have you tried with `OnItemSelectedListener` ?

Comment: You should add that code after findviewbyid s for spinners.

Comment: tried that gives the following error "The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get updated value as user select item from spinner,

You have to implement spinner's onItemSelectedListner

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {

         // Do your stuff here for spinner1

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

}); 
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {

         // Do your stuff here for spinner3

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this could you help me as to where to insert this in myyy code above I have tried inserting it after i set the view but no matter where I insert it i get errors

Comment: You can add this code inside onCreate method at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate views or data on the selection of item in `Spinner` you need to implement 
`ItemSelectedListener` to the particular `Spinner`.

Sample Code:

```
// in onCreate() or where you want to bind this Views with XML views
{
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    // mItemSelectedListener Object of OnItemSelectedListener to handle Item Selection to Spinners.
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(mItemSelectedListener);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(mItemSelectedListener);
}

// Creating an Object of Anonymous Class so no need to create another instance for same class
// OutSide of onCreate() method.
OnItemSelectedListener mItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
              // Manipulates Views at selection of item in Spinner1
            break;
        case R.id.spinner3:
              // Manipulates Views at selection of item in Spinner3
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
};
```